# Is there a way to track downloads from a static webpage?

Tags: google-analytics

All answers I found previously relied on tying the pdf download to an actual URL, but that isn't what I have.

I have a static website and on it is a button to click and download a pdf. Is there a way to track these clicks/downloads?

Comment: If JS is fine, just create a function that logs to your analytic before redirecting to the PDF, if that's unacceptable, host a cloud function that returns the file after logging.

Comment: I currently don't have any backend implemented, could I do either of these without it?

Comment: JS doesn't require any backend, cloud function is hosted for free by Google so all your static site care is there's a different URL to link. Read about them first.

Comment: How would I keep track of it using javascript? In order to save that data wouldn't I need to write the download count to a file? In order to keep that count between instances wouldn't I need a backend?

Comment: The point of using analytics is so you save the count there, no need for another backend

Answer (score 1):

Either add google analytics script and add an event that fires on button click, or use Google Tag Manager and create a Click trigger to send an event.

Comment: Is there a tutorial where I could learn to add the google analytics script? I can't seem to find one for clicking. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: You can try this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events